# SQlite3 Optimization: Store external file name in db? Or just have a huge number of rows?

Tags: sqlite

I am a newbie with no comp sci background. So please forgive me for whatever dumb stuff I may say. I am working on a solar power monitoring project to monitor the power output of the solar power systems my company installs. I am writing a client that will query the inverter (for power output, voltage output, current output, system errors/faults, etc--which constitutes one "reading") of each of our monitoring customers every 15 minutes for as long as they have their system--which means roughly 35k readings per year per customer. So I was thinking of organizing my sqlite3 database in one of the two following ways.

(1) Have the database be two tables, one table with regular customer information (name, email, etc) and another much bigger table where each row represents one reading and includes the customer id and timestamp of reading as identifiers. Which means roughly 35k rows will be being added to this bigger table per customer per year. (Data more than two years old will be pared down and archived.)

OR

(2) Store all readings in a csv file (one csv file per customer) and store the csv file name in my table with regular customer information

This database will be serving a website (built on rails if that makes any difference for options) where customers will be able to view their power output data. I want to minimize the amount of time it will take to load their output data on login. I basically don't have a clear idea of the amount of time it would take for my computer to open and read in lines from a text file versus open, look for (based on customer id) and read in the data from a huge sqlite3 table--and therefore am having trouble knowing how to judge between the two options above. Also I'm having trouble gauging the limits of sqlite3 where it functions optimally despite having read some about it (I don't think I have the background to understand the reading I did because it seems to say 100s of millions of rows are just fine when I read other people's comments seeming to say just the opposite.). I am also open to a completely different option as I'm not married to anything right now. Whatever makes things load faster. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I agree that storing all data in the database is Ok.  Maybe, you will need also third table with some aggregated data (one row per hour or few hours).  Also, what is insert rate will you have?

Answer (score 0):

SQL applications in general do very well with large data sets, as long as the columns being queried are indexed. You should keep them in the same database. It will take a huge lot less to obtain the data from the database than for parsing CSV files. Databases are created with the purpose of storing and retrieving data, CSV files are not.

I use MySQL databases with tens of millions of rows per table and queries return results in fractions of a second. SQLite might be faster.

Just make sure you create indexes for what you will be searching.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the parsed data in sqlite would definitely be a timesaver if you're doing any kind of repeated data mining on it. CSV Parsing overhead would almost instantly eat up any database space/time savings you'd gain.

As for efficiency, you'd have to test it. There's no one hard fast rule that says "use this database" or "use that database". It's ALWAYS a "depends on the scenario". SQLite may be perfect for you in this case, but be useless for someone else with a slightly different workload.

Answer (score 0):

I would do option 1, but use a database server such as PostgreSQL instead of SQLite.

SQLite will lock the table on update so you may run into locking issues if you read and write to the table a lot. SQLite is better suited for single user applications on the desktop or in a smartphone.

You can easily have millions of rows without it causing any problems.

Comment: By locking on update, do you mean that I won't be able say insert a new user if the program that inserts the readings is also in the middle of an insertion (which'll be happening pretty often every 15 minutes though hopefully for only a fraction of a second)? Then I will definitely be looking into PostgreSQL.

Comment: Exactly. You can only do one update operation at a time. The rest will be queued up waiting for the lock to be released.

Comment: Also if it is locked while there is an insertion happening, will an insertion attempt by another program simply be unsuccessful? or is there possibility for my database to be corrupted somehow?

Comment: I see. Sorry I posted my last question before I saw the reply for my previous question. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is speculative on my part. The other insert will most likely not fail, only be delayed. If it gets delayed long enough it may fail depending on how your client code is written. I don't think your database will be corrupted. Only slow and possibly deadlocked. As I wrote earlier, if you can go with a real database server as those are built for multi user and concurrency.